# binomial distribution z-score value too large

Tags: statistics

i try to solve this question 
by 
n =500 ,p=0.9/100 and q=1-0.9/100

but im geting z-score and mean very large .

Paycheck Errors The payroll department of a hospital has found that in one year, 0.9% of its paychecks are calcu- lated incorrectly. The hospital has 500 employees.
(a) What is the probability that in one month’s records no paycheck errors are made?
(b) What is the probability that in one month’s records at least one paycheck error is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z transformation is a poor approximation to the binomial distribution for `npq < 10`.  For your problem `npq == 4.4595`, so the Z approximation is a no-go.

You'd do better to calculate it exactly as a binomial using software, or approximate it as a Poisson with rate λ=np.  Once you solve part (a), part (b) is just the complement.

I went ahead and calculated part (a) both ways.  The Poisson approximation differs from the exact calculation by only 0.00022.

Answer (score -1):

You should use binomial distribution formula rather than sampling distribution formula.